# Delivering report for push notification in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, background

Currently I am working on a chat based app using socket. In android it works fine since android has no restriction in working with socket in background. I searched a lot about running socket in iOS in background. iOS is very strict in that case. So that I found sending push notification from server is good instead of sending from socket. But I want to send delivery reports of messages whenever I received a push without opening the app.

Is there any way to do that? If I can't send emit socket, it's ok. Can I send a server call at least?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can not send server call until unless your app is in running or active state.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh thanks for the reply. can i work socket on background...

Comment: you can try VOIP

Comment: let me try... any way thanks,...

Answer (score 1):

Now in iOS 10 and iOS 11, you should be using `PushKit` for handling push notifications for incoming `Voice over IP` calls. So when you build your app against the iOS 10/11 SDK, you need to move over to `PushKit` (which can be supported all the way back to iOS 8, but once you move to iOS 10/11 the recommendation is to update your minimum deployment target to iOS 9).

```
// Link to the PushKit framework
import PushKit

// Trigger VoIP registration on launch
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    self.voipRegistration()
    return true
}

// Register for VoIP notifications
func voipRegistration {
    let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()

    // Create a push registry object
    let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(mainQueue)

    // Set the registry's delegate to self
    voipRegistry.delegate = self

    // Set the push type to VoIP
    voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushTypeVoIP]
}
```

Comment: is there any restriction for registering my app as an VOIP app. since i am not using any call protocols am only using socket for sending and receiving messages. if i go for that, will app store rejects it.

Comment: Sorry, Muhammed, I don't know it. App Store regulations is surprise for everyone))))